# cocos2d sprites disable touches

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, xcode

i haves game with cocos2d i have many sprites
i'm using touch to sprite with this

```
CGRectContainsPoint([[gameImages objectAtIndex:i] boundingBox], location)
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
```

but when i touched the sprite must be deleted
i have

```
[self removeChild:[gameImages objectAtIndex:bacvacIndexner[0]] cleanup:YES];
```

but the touch works because i use the object coordinates and i cant delete object when i removin that from child
what can i do?why i can get the touch event for sprite . are anything without coordinate method?

Comment: Your question is poorly written. Whether you dont speak English natively or do, please revise it to make more sense.

Comment: Sorry, I have to agree with @Sold Out Activist.  I feel I am very close to understanding your question, but not quite enough to actually answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback so a higher class remove the object. Inside your to-be-removed class:

```
[self.touchDelegate performSelector:@selector(removeMe:) withObject:self afterDelay:0.0f];
```